# Wifi not working on Lenovo Legion Y540-15IRH

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lenovo-laptop

I have tried [this](https://unixblogger.com/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/), but I can't get the wifi working. Only ethernet is working. You can ask what commands I should run to give you more info :)

Accoring to `lshw` the network card is this: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller

Here's my laptop specs:
- Intel Core i5-9300H Processor (2.40GHz, up to 4.10GHz with Turbo Boost, 4 Cores, 8MB Cache)
- Latest Manjaro Gnome
- 32GB (16+16) DDR4 2666MHz SoDIMM
- 1TB Hard Drive, 7200RPM, 2.5", 7mm
- 512GB Solid State Drive, M.2 2242, PCIe-NVMe, TLC
- 15.6" FHD (1920x1080), IPS, 300nits, Anti-glare, 60Hz
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX1650 4GB GDDR5 128bit
- Lenovo Wireless 2x2AC, Bluetooth Version 4.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and used this to restore my Wifi:
`rmmod ideapad_laptop`

To make it permanent add the following to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`:
`blacklist ideapad_laptop`